# How to create a Spannable GridView with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to create something like this where the items can be dragged around with the current state of jetpack compose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's not a composable to do that out of the box, if that's what your asking. It is, however, possible to create something like this, after defining exactly how do you want items to be positioned. It's not viable to post an answer here since we don't even know how the composable would behave, but if you started it, we could help with specifics.